# Is there a word or term for my idea?

Tags: reality, term

I recently has the idea the reality is inescapable because it is everywhere. I think everyone knows that you cannot escape reality, but I thought that if reality is everywhere-in front of you, behind you, above you, etc.-then even if you could magically go to a new reality, you have still not escaped reality. If there is nothing, then that is reality. If this computer is just energy, and not matter, then that is reality. Is there a word to describe this?

Comment: Sounds a bit like Parmenides' arguments (summarized [here](http://faculty.washington.edu/smcohen/320/parm1.htm)) that it is meaningless to talk about nothingness or nonexistence--as the summary says, "That which is not cannot be thought about or spoken about", and "Parmenides is posing constraints on language and on thought, a limit on what can be spoken of or thought about: we cannot speak or think about things that are not (real), that do not exist."

Comment: Kind of tangentially related, but matter is a kind of energy, not something different from energy.  Just so you know.  Often in fiction "energy" is used for something insubstantial and often glowing, like a laser beam, but really in physics energy is a quality everything has.  A laser beam is one form of energy, a block of wood is another form, just as validly energy as the laser beam.

Answer (score 1):

If the common word *inescapable reality* doesn't satisfy you, then Heidegger's *Dasein* (usually translated to English as "being in the world") referenced [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dasein) may be a philosophical term which is similar to your idea:

> Heidegger uses the expression Dasein to refer to the experience of being that is peculiar to human beings. Thus it is a form of being that is aware of and must confront such issues as personhood, mortality and the dilemma or paradox of living in relationship with other humans while being ultimately alone with oneself.

Or you might be interested in Eastern philosophy's inescapable Infinite *Indra's Net* referenced [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indra%27s_net):

> "Indra's net" is an infinitely large net of cords owned by the Vedic deva Indra, which hangs over his palace on Mount Meru, the axis mundi of Buddhist and Hindu cosmology. In this metaphor, Indra's net has a multifaceted jewel at each vertex, and each jewel is reflected in all of the other jewels.

> By that net, O Indra, pounce upon all the enemies so that none of the enemies may escape the arrest and punishment